# Model form within another model's form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model, associations

I have a `Content` model, a `Playlist` model and a join association in a model called `PlaylistItem`.

This is how they're connected:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_items
  has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_items
end

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_items, -> { order 'position ASC' }
  has_many :contents, through: :playlist_items
end

class PlaylistItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :playlist
end
```

When I edit a `Playlist`, the form only shows its field `Name`, that's the only attribute that it has. But I want to be able to add a `Content` to that `Playlist` (in a certain `position`, that's the `PlaylistItem`s only attribute) within that form.

How can I do that?

---

This is the code I have by now:

```
<%= form_for(@playlist) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :playlist_items do |builder| %>
        <fieldset>
          <%= builder.label :content, "Content ID" %><br>
          <%= builder.text_area :content_id %>
        </fieldset>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: [Nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)

Comment: I've already seen that, but I can't get it right.

Comment: Can you add to your question what you have in your form so far?

Comment: Okay. I've put it there.

Comment: What does attributes does the `Content` model have, i.e. what columns are in the `contents` table. In addition, would you like to select from existing `contents` in your form, or create and/or `contents` in it?

Comment: I'd like to select from existing contents. A `Content` has an `id` and a `title`, among others. But those are the only ones needed to this, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can let you `Playlist` model accept nested attributes for `playlist_items`.

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_items, -> { order 'position ASC' }
  has_many :contents, through: :playlist_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :playlist_items
end
```

Then, you can add `content_id` as a collection select, which will create a drop down selection of contents for each playlist item.

```
<%= f.fields_for :playlist_items do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label :position %><br>
  <%= builder.integer :position %><br>
  <%= builder.label :content %><br>
  <%= builder.collection_select :content_id, @contents, :id, :title, include_blank: 'Please Select' %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, in your controller, you'll need to allow playlist items attributes to be passed as params, and also set your `@contents` instance variable.

```
class PlaylistController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_contents, only: [:new, :edit]

  def edit
    @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
    # Build 10 playlist_items to be added to your playlist
    10.times do; @playlist.playlist_items.build; end
  end

  private
    def load_contents
      @contents = Content.all # or another query to get the specific contents you'd like
    end

    def playlist_params
      params.require(:playlist).permit(:name, playlist_items_attributes: [:id, :position, :content_id])
    end
end
```

Remember that you'll need to build each playlist item that you'd like to use. You can do that in your `new` and `edit` methods as you desire.

Comment: Thank you. This is almost what I wanted. But how do I add a new playlist_item here? I mean, a content to the playlist? It only allows me to edit those that already exist.

Comment: The easy way would be to do something like `10.times do; @playlist.playlist_items.build; end` and always have 10 additional `playlist_items`.

Comment: I didn't understand, sorry. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Add that snippet of code to your `update` method in `PlaylistController`, after setting your `@playlist` instance variable.

Comment: If you'd like a button or link for adding a new `playlist_item`, that will be a bit more complex. I'd suggest checking out the [Nested Form Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) for help on doing that. You could also look into nested form **gems**, such as [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), or [awesome_nested_fields](https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields).

Comment: I still don't understand what does that snippet of code. What I meant is that with your answer when I go to Playlist -> Edit view, what I have is a listing of the editable playlist_items. But I want to be able to add a content to a playlist, adding a playlist_item automatically, with the `content_id` and the corresponding `playlist_id`, also with the position.

Comment: I added the code snippet I was talking about to my answer. I don't know what your last sentence means. If you mean that you want to be able to press a button to add a new content to a playlist, then you should check out the RailsCast I linked in my above comment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.